# What is the use of '@f' in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

#the code given is:

```
def f(a):
    print('hello')

@f    

def f(a,b):
    return a%b

f(4,0)
```

What I expected to happen was a zero division error, instead it printed hello.
When I write the same code without '@f'
it gives the expected result as output
I've never seen symbol/expression being used in python
This is new and Google too has nothing about it

Comment: It's a *decorator* syntax

Comment: Using `f` to name everything makes this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Note that the "hello" came from the application of the decorator, NOT from your explicit call to `f()` (which should have produced a "'NoneType' object is not callable" error).

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is about more than just decorator syntax.

Comment: This behaves much more like you'd expect if you just make the decorator return the function object that was passed to it.

Answer (score 4):

Decorator syntax is a shorthand for a particular function application.

```
@f
def f(a, b):
    return a%b
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
def tmp(a, b):
    return a % b

tmp2 = f(tmp)

f = tmp2
```

(Reusing the name `f` for everything makes this tricker to understand.)

First, your division-by-zero function is defined. Next, your *original* function `f` is called: it prints `hello` and returns `None`. Finally, you attempt to call `None` with two arguments, but it isn't callable, resulting in the `TypeError` you allude to.

In short, the decorator syntax takes care of treating all the things that would otherwise have been named `f` as distinct objects and applying things in the correct order.